# Is the phrase "Zowie, I'm young!" a reference?

Tags: reference, brooklyn-nine-nine

In *Brooklyn Nine-Nine* Season 6, Episode 8, title *He Said, She Said*, Captain Holt says the phrase

> Zowie, I'm young!

to Terry and Boyle upon discovering the Disco Strangler is still alive (around 16 minutes into the episode, immediately after Holt receives a fax).

It isn't a phrase I'm familiar with, and I am unable to find anything online about it except for articles relating to this particular episode. However, the name "Zowie" strikes me as very odd, and I feel as though he is quoting something when he says this.

**Is the phrase "Zowie, I'm young!" a reference?**

Comment: Possibly related to an old cartoon featuring a talking shark called Jabberjaws - I seem to remember it said "Zowie" a fair bit...?  Not sure exactly what the reference might be though in B99

Comment: "Zowie" is just another term for "Wow".

Comment: It may be a reference to the movie *Some Like It Hot,* 1959, Joe E. Brown's character, who says it all the time, possibly even this exact phrase.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is a good one. 
"Zowie!" is a thing that cowboys said in old westerns. Because they couldn't swear. Something like "todly-o" or "gorsh dam".

It's a word that means "Huuray!". And it's also, a word that is no longer used.

From [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/zowie)

> The word zowie was inspired by the sound of a speeding vehicle-a new
>   phenomenon when the word entered the lexicon in 1902, the year before
>   the Ford Motor Company sold its first car

So it's a joke on how Holt is really old when, feeling young, he use phrase that is 80 years old.

Comment: Ahh, so "zowie" isn't a name in this instance, just an exclamation! Okay it feels like less of a reference when "zowie" is just a word, I understand now; I think seeing it capitalised (for starting a sentence) and being aware of Zowie Bowie had me barking up the wrong tree. Although I've had to have the joke explained to me (nothing kills a joke like explaining it), I do have a new appreciation for the scene now, so cheers!

Comment: It is clearly not a word that is no longer used, since Holt used it. Q.E.D. :)

Comment: You're correct that it's a joke about it being an old-fashioned exclamation, but I think it means something closer to "wow", rather than "hooray". So the line translates to "wow, I'm young", which is ironic because he used a super old-timey word to express his youth.